Role-based Authorization on Oracle APEX
I have a custom auth scheme named CustomAuthorization with the following PL/SQL:
DECLARE
is_admin_flag VARCHAR2(1);
BEGIN
 -- Retrieve admin flag for the current user
 SELECT is_admin INTO is_admin_flag
 FROM users
 WHERE UPPER(username) = UPPER(:APP_USER);

 -- Check if the user is an admin
 IF is_admin_flag = 'Y' THEN
     RETURN TRUE;  -- Grant access to admin users
 ELSE
     RETURN FALSE; -- Deny access to non-admin users
 END IF;
END;

Now, I want some pages that I want only non-authenticated users can access. I thought that doing something like this would allow for that. See page settings below.

But I still get the error from CustomAuthorization scheme. I even tried Must Not Be Public User, but I'm still pulling my hair out. Any help would be appreciated.
TIA :)

From own experience... this can be really frustrating. Probably the authorization scheme return value is cached. This is visible in debug logs when page is run in debug mode.
Usually, when developing auth schemes I add a page process to the page I'm working on that calls
apex_authorization.reset_cache;

When all is good, remove that call.
Note that if the auth scheme that is failing is on page you'll have to call this reset_cache procedure on another page that is authorized or has no auth scheme.

Oh, man. I've been on Google, Gemini, and the docs. After a few hair strands, I wondered why the CustomAuthorization scheme was given priority. Removing it on the Application Config Settings worked! The page's security scheme was being overridden by the global scheme nonetheless. Having each page define its scheme did it for me. Ha!

My solution was setting the setting Edit Application Definition > Security > Authorization to - No application authorization required - and then having page-specific schemes. I'm wondering if this will come and bite me later.

You could also create 2 applications, one with auth and one without.

Really? Got me wondering how their pages will interlink without some hacking going around.

Yes you can it's a very common pattern. Don't know the details of the top of my head. But if one app does not have authorization like in your case it should be a no brainer. All pages would be "Public" anyway

I see. However, in my case, the web app targets three user levels. An admin, a normal user, and public pages.
